# Bash Shell Script For Word Counting

Tags: bash, shell, count, statistics, cpu-word

For some time now, I've been trying to write a bash script, which should read a *.txt file and output word occurrences. I had no luck so far. I know the algorithm, the only problem is the syntax.

How should this script work?

When I type `./myScript.sh myTextFile.txt` in a terminal, it should output all the word occurrences in a sorted order from largest to smallest in percentage like this:

```
17 is 7.1%  
12 all 6.4%  
10 house 5.5%  
5 tree 3.7%
```

....................and soo on.

If I put a switch `./myScript.sh -x 3 myTextFile.txt` it should only output the words longer than 3 characters.

If I put a switch `./myScript.sh -y 4 myTextFile.txt` it should only output the words who occur 4 times or more. Here I had a lot of problems on how to determine which switches were used and what value are they holding.

And of course, if I put a file that does not exist or a wrong switch the script should threw an error.

Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Better start showing your attempts and what you are missing, so we can try to assist

Comment: Can you show your script so we can help?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` to get the word count:

```
 awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){a[$i]++;tot++}}END{for(j in a) {printf("%s %s %2.1f%\n",a[j],j,a[j]/tot*100)}}' myTextFile.txt | sort -g
```

This `awk`  command fills the array `a[]` with all words, and their index count.

`tot` is the total number of words encountered.

The `END` statement loops through the array and show the count, word, and percentage.

`sort -g` is performing a numerical sort based on the count number.